# Link to order from order confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.7

I`m trying to add link to order review in order confirmation email:

```
<a href="{{store url="sales/order/view/order_id/}}"{{var order.id}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">
```

But when customer get the email it links just to `http://mysite/sales/order/view/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your quotes.

```
<a href="{{store url="sales/order/view/order_id/"}}{{var order.id}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
Hi,
<a href="{{store url="sales/order/view/order_id/"}}{{var order.id}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">

This is okay but it still not shows full link. It shows only sales/order/view/.

To show **order_id/**, you have to create Custom Variable.
Go to **System >> Custom Variables**.
Check Image below.
**http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/1470/tI8BGv.png**

Now create custom variable shown in image with any name.
Now revise the code and change the line.

<a href="{{store url="sales/order/view/"}}{{customVar code=static_url}}{{var order.id}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">

It's working fine for me.
Thanks & Regards.
```